# Is it possible to rename files selected by ls?

Tags: command-line, files, ls, rename

I have some files I downloaded recently and  I want to name. It is possible to do something like:

```
rename 's/ /_/g' $(ls -t | head -n5)
```

Actually, I would like to rename last downloaded 5 files.

Any idea?

Comment: Don't parse `ls`! Use `find -exec` instead.

Comment: @wjandrea I'm trying to come up with a full answer for this, but `find` does not seem to have any options for sorting output by modification time (like `ls` does) - any ideas?

Comment: One-liner in `zsh`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35844/170373

Comment: Given the complexities of the answers, this might be easier if you just told us the filenames. Then we can know whether or not they contain special characters and possibly write simpler solutions.

Comment: @wjandrea This solution (`ls -1t | head -n5 | xargs -I {} rename 's/ /_/g' {}`) is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I have to note, parsing `ls` is generally not recommended. Its output is meant for human consumption, and this solution will fail for some legitimate file names (like those which contain newline characters, for example)

With that said, the simplest solution does seem to be using `ls` (as `find` does not offer a sort-by-modification-date option). For this, you can use pipes and the `xargs` command to execute the final rename.

In short:

```
ls -1t | head -n5 | xargs -I {} rename 's/ /_/g' {}
```

This uses your original command almost exactly, but with `xargs` to do the final completion. `xargs` will take in a number of newline-separated arguments, and pass them all to a single `rename` command.

## Caveats

This should work - but parsing `ls` is fragile. This breaks for file names which contain the newline character; using a command that's meant for parsing like `find` would be much better.

However, I don't know how to sort by last modification date with `find`. If someone else knows how to do this, you'd probably end up with something like:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -print0 | sort <???> -Z | head -z -n5 | xargs -0 rename 's/ /_/g'
```

If `<???>` were a valid argument, this command chain would tell `find` to output files in the current directory separated with a NUL character, and then `sort`, `head`, and `xargs` would all accept this as the deliminator rather than a newline - making the whole process much more consistent. Feel free to comment or edit this if you know how to do this, and want to replace the `ls` answer with this bottom part.

Comment: I think, newlines in filenames are possible and legal, but [not legitimate](https://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html)

Comment: +1 for the caveat, but note that there is no benefit in using `ls -t | head -n5 | xargs rename . . . ` over `rename $(ls . . .)`.

Comment: @Philippos they are "legitimate" whatever that means. They exist in the wild and can often be created by accident. Some people might even create them on purpose. It's not only about newlines though, the parsing `ls` approach would also fail if a file contains a `\r`, for example .

Comment: @terdon I don't like arguing about words, but what you say fits "legal", but not "legitimate". If you call it legal, you encourage people to take care for the possibility in their scripts. But if you call it legitimate, you encourage people to produce filenames with control characters. But I find it important to tell people not to fool around with that possibility. Sorry for nitpicking.

Comment: @Philippos bit of a pointless statement then. You can tell people not to use newlines in filenames all you want, but you'd still have to take care of the possibility when you don't know what filenames will be thrown at your script.

Comment: @Philippos no argument there, of course you shouldn't create such files. but they are sometimes created, as I said often by accident, so we need to be able to deal with them.

Comment: @Dabo The `find` pipeline you want: 
`find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn | sed -zn '1,5s/^[0-9]*.[0-9]* //p'`

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, [parsing `ls` is fragile](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It will break if your file names have any type of weirdness (spaces, newlines, control characters etc). Since you want to replace spaces with `_`, your suggested approach will fail. A safe way to do this would be:

```
stat --printf '%n/%Y\0' * | sort -rz -t'/' -k 2 | head -z -n 3 | 
    cut -d'/' -z -f 1 | xargs -0 perl-rename 's/ /_/g'
```

- `stat --printf '%n/%Y\0' *` : this will print out the name (`%n`) of every file or directory in the current directory followed by a slash (`/`; I am using a slash since that is not allowed in a file name so can safely be used as a separator) and the file's modification time in seconds since the epoch (`%Y`) and finally a NULL character (`\0`).
- `sort -rz -k 2` : this will take NULL-separated input (`-z`) and sort it in reverse order (`-r`) based on the value in the second `/`-separated (`-t'/'`) field of each line (`-k 2`).
- `head -z -n 5` : keep the first 5 (`-n 5`) null-separated (`-z`) lines.
- `cut -d'/' -z -f 1` : print the 1st (`-f 1`) `/`-separated (`-d /`) field of null-delimited (`-z`) data.

Answer (score 0):

I just gave `ls -q` a try:

```
IFS='
'
for file in `ls -tr1q|tail -n5`; do
  rename 's/ /_/g' "$file"
done
```

Does the desired rename, even for filenames with newline or other control characters, although it gives an error:

```
Unsuccessful stat on filename containing newline at /usr/bin/rename line 59
```

(with perl v5.20.2)