# How to rename file from ls?

Tags: 18.04, bash, rename

basically, my download directory is always full. Every time I download new file, I use command like `ls -t | head -n1` to show the file I just Downloaded. Some time, I would like to just `rename` dynamically the newly downloaded with sometime like  like `ls -t | sed -n '2,2p' | xargs rename`.

Any idea how to do this ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/909804/is-it-possible-to-rename-files-selected-by-ls has all you need but DO take note of https://askubuntu.com/questions/909804/is-it-possible-to-rename-files-selected-by-ls#comment1430336_909804 "Don't parse ls! Use find -exec instead"

Comment: This kind of thing is easier in `zsh` - whose glob qualifiers allow you to do things like `*(.om[1])` to order plain files by modification time and select the first one

Comment: How you download the file? in command line or GUI? with which command? some allowing you to specify the output downloaded file name